# Retrieving ids from a LINQ query result

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with a library that performs an operation (I think with LINQ) in a function and returns a collection of objects like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ColorInformation>
```

this "ColorInformation" is a class that looks like this:

```
public class ColorInformation
{
    private readonly System.Drawing.Color color;
    private readonly string rowTitle;
    private readonly System.Collections.Generic.List<int> ids;

    public ColorInformation(System.Drawing.Color color, string rowTitle,
        System.Collections.Generic.List<int> ids)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.rowTitle = rowTitle;
        this.ids = ids;
    }

    public string RowTitle
    {
        get { return rowTitle; }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Color Color
    {
        get { return color; }
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.List<int> Ids
    {
        get { return ids; }
    }
}
```

I am interested in retrieving ALL the ids of ALL the objects in the collection returned. I have tried this:

```
var myids = from ids in theCollectionReturned select ids.Ids;
```

That gives me a Collection of Lists with the ids. What I actually want is just one list with ALL the integer ids in it. So, there has to be a cast or some conversion somewhere and I am not sure how to do that. Any help, tips, readings, code, examples would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What I actually want is just one list with ALL the integer ids in it.

It sounds like you want:

```
var ids = theCollectionReturned.SelectMany(info => info.Ids);
```

Comment: Just out of interest Jon, do you prefer the fluent extension method syntax over the query syntax?  I prefer the fluent syntax myself... I find it a bit more succinct

Comment: @DanFox: Where the query expression syntax *is* briefer, I'll use it. But I'd rather use this than `from info in theCollectionReturned from id in info.Ids select id` which is far cruftier. I find that the fluent syntax is often simpler for single calls, e.g. just a Select, just a Where, or just a SelectMany. Query expressions come into their own with joins, groups etc. It's best to be comfortable with both, and use whichever one is most appropriate for any given query.

Comment: Wow! that was quick! Thanks Jon, that is what I needed.